# Eclipse Luna – AutoIndent is inconsistent

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I upgraded to Luna and have a problem with auto-formatting, more specifically auto-indentation. The About Eclipse dialog verifies that I am running 4.4.0.

When the code auto-indents on save, it seems to jump back and forth between two different ways of indenting it regarding the number of spaces. Note the level of indentation:

```
doSomething( "arg0",
    "arg1" );
```

and

```
doSomething( "arg0",
        "arg1" );
```

This is extremely annoying when using SCM like git. What's causing this? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found this bug reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434962

The fix mentioned there is to uncheck "Correct indentation" in the save actions. Weirdly, it will still correct indentation, but the bug is gone.

*Update:* Eclipse Mars also has some issues. One bug can be found [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467618). As a workaround, see [here](http://eclipse-n-mati.blogspot.de/2015/06/eclipse-mars-how-to-switch-back-to.html) how to use the old formatter in Mars.

Comment: Thanks. I think in my case the indentation is still working because of the formatter (which is configured to run on save and it has indent features).

Comment: This was also driving me crazy. My formatter was also configured to apply indentation. That must be the issue